# Magento 2 add configurable product to quote with a custom price, the price is always the original from database

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, quote, simple-product

When adding a configurable product to a quote and trying to set a custom price on the product, magento is always showing the product original price in the cart and not the custom price:

```
$originalProduct <-- object of original in a loop of products

$clonedProduct = clone $originalProduct; // have to clone for it to add a new row and not override the product if it's the same as an existing one in the quote

$quote->addProduct($clonedProduct,new DataObject([
    'qty'=>1,
    'product'=>$clonedProduct->getId(),
    'super_attribute'=>$attributes,
    'price' => 1.99
]);
```

The product for example is originally 4.99 and i want it in my quote as 1.99 , but it's completely ignoring the price i set, everything else works.